# Not apply a configuration to a certain class of multiple classes in one block in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say that I have this css:

```
.class1, class2, class3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I want to do some changes and not apply the `position:absolute` to `.class2`. Is it possible to do something like this in css instead of creating two declarations by separate? I know the syntax is wrong my intention is that you understand what I mean:

```
.class1, class2, class3{
    position: absolute (not: .class2);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: `.class1, class2, class3{` should be `.class1, .class2, .class3{`. You're missing the periods. But to answer your question no, you can't do that with plain CSS. Maybe with a CSS preprocessor though...

Comment: No, that is not possible. `:not()` exists, but it is a selector itself, so you can only use it in the selector part of your rule to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exclusion inside the CSS rule is not possible. What you can do is to only put the one parameter that should be different into another rule that follows the rule for all three (overwriting that parameter for one class), like

```
.class1, .class2, .class3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
.class2 {
    position: static;
}
```